# Referencing checkBoxes

Tags: android, checkbox

the program that is being worked upon is using an api to collect all the information required, thus making the activity very dynamic. Due to this dynamic nature a presentation layout, say x.xml is being used to specify the styling of those elements.
the layout contains a title, information and a checkbox. the problem that i am having is that i can only refer to the last checkbox of the layout since all of them have the same id as specified in the layout. is there any way i can refer/loop through all the checkboxes in the layout ? not just the last checkbox element using this type of layout ?

the layout file

Contains the following:

```
<TextView>
<TextView>
<CheckBox android:id>
```

the java class the following code to refer to it:

```
CheckBox check =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
check.setOnClickListener ....
```

and since I am working with apis I am using the `AsyncTask's OnPostExecute` to fill in the activity.

Answer (score 2):

This is really easy with my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library. In your Activity, call this:

```
$.with(this).selectByType(Checkbox.class.getName()).each(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        Checkbox cb = (Checkbox) droidQuery.view(0);
        //TODO: manipulate each checkbox here.
    }
});
```

To add a click listener, just add the chain call `click` (either instead, or at the end):

**By iteself**

```
$.with(this).selectByType(Checkbox.class.getName()).click(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        Checkbox cb = (Checkbox) droidQuery.view(0);
        //TODO: handle the clicked Checkbox
    }
});
```

**Chained call**

```
$.with(this).selectByType(Checkbox.class.getName()).each(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        Checkbox cb = (Checkbox) droidQuery.view(0);
        //TODO: manipulate each checkbox here.
    }
}).click(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        Checkbox cb = (Checkbox) droidQuery.view(0);
        //TODO: handle the clicked Checkbox
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if all checkboxes have the same ID, you will only ever get one reference to them. Perhaps try create a view, and progmatically create CheckBoxes to add them to the view. You can then have a `HashMap<String, Checkbox>` where your string is the ID of the checkbox, and therefore you can retrieve the correct checkboxes at runtime.

Comment: dont mind for asking ... how can that be done in code ?? examples please.